# Cant get spree to install on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I keep getting this Money gem error

```
undefined method `assume_from_symbol' for Money:Class
```

I've tried everything from adding

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-2-stable'
```

and also tried

```
gem 'money', '~> 6.0.1'
```

I've tried doing a few clean installs as well. Same thing. Any fix?

Thanks

Comment: Have you run 'bundle install' and restarted your rails server after modifying your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

### I'm using this version of Rails & Spree and it's working fine form me.

```
ruby "2.0.0"
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
```

#### Spree app gems

```
gem "spree", "~> 2.1.4"
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => "spree/spree_auth_devise", :branch => '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree_variant_options', :github => "extragen/spree_variant_options", :branch => '2-1-    stable'
```

================================================================================
Add this in your Gemfile

```
 gem 'money', '6.0.1'
```

Run

```
bundle update
```

Restart the server.

Hope this will work and if still you are any issue then feel free to post exception here.

Comment: I added the exact same lines as you stated, but i'm still having this error undefined method `assume_from_symbol' for Money:Class

Comment: Please setup a fresh project.

Comment: I went through the same thing. Still run into the same error.